# What does this anonymous-like C block mean?

Tags: c, syntax

I saw similar code when reading a reference, and I tried this piece of code which can compile and run:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;
void main() {
  (void) ({ x = 0x1234; });
  printf("x=0x%x\n", x);
}
```

But I don't know how should I interpret this line: `(void) ({ x = 0x1234; });`. I mean, it looks like an anonymous function which takes in no parameter and return void? Not really I think. And I didn't find any reference for this weird syntax, how should I understand that and is there any reference for the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a GCC extension (not standard C) called a [statement-expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). Statements inside it are evaluated, and its value is that of the last expression statement evaluated in it.

The example you show is not useful since the value is discarded with the cast to `void`.